# Error deploying Rails project with Capistrano and Assembla

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, assembla

I started a new project in rails and setup a server and assembla to have my subversion files in Assembla and to deploy with Capistrano to my server.

The problem is that when I do cap deploy I get an error message:

```
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "svn info https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/myappname/trunk/  -rHEAD"
    command finished in 4687ms
  * executing "svn export -q  -r4 https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/myappname/trunk/ /home/administrator/myappname/releases/20111028232813 && (echo 4 > /home/administrator/myappname/releases/20111028232813/REVISION)"
    servers: ["my.server.url"]
Password: 
    [my.server.url] executing command
 ** [my.server.url :: out] Authentication realm: <https://subversion.assembla.com:443> Assembla Restricted Area
 ** Password for 'administrator':
 ** [my.server.url :: out]
 ** [my.server.url :: out] Authentication realm: <https://subversion.assembla.com:443> Assembla Restricted Area
 ** Username:
```

beyond that I add my Assembla Username and it just freezes there and nothing else happens

My deploy.rb has the correct svn url and id and password (I made sure it by checking the url in a browser and entering those credentials)

I also tried svn cleanup as suggested in [other post](http://forum.assembla.com/forums/2-Subversion/topics/2341-Can-t-Commit-to-SVN-repo--userid-pass-not-working), but I didn't have any luck.

How can I fix this problem?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a checkout of the repository on the server, saving the password and then setting deploy.rb's svn info like this:

```
set :svn_user, Proc.new { Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt("SVN user: ") }
set :svn_password, Proc.new { Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt("SVN password for '#{svn_user}': ") }
set :repository,
Proc.new { "--username #{svn_user} --password #{svn_password} your_svn_url" }
```

where your_svn_url is set with http and not https

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @marimaf wrote, you can also set environment variables for the svn user name and password (if you wish, recognizing the security issues) and make this pretty prompt free.

So,

```
$ export SVN_USER=username
$ export SVN_PASSWORD=password
```

and replace the sets above with,

```
set :svn_user, ENV['SVN_USER'] || Proc.new { Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt("SVN user: ") }
set :svn_password, ENV['SVN_PASSWORD'] || Proc.new { Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt("SVN password for '#{svn_user}': ") }
```